# AngularJS - highlighting part of text causes broken words in non-English language

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, arabic-support

In the snippet below, I'm trying to highlight each part of the words that matches the search input in Arabic language, but this makes the letters separate in the text. How can I solve this problem?

Try to input `مست` in the field, and you'll see the problem.

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("main", function($scope){
$scope.content="تتيح لك إدارة المستخدمين العديد من الخدمات الأساسية كعرض مستخدمي النظام والتعديل عليها وحذفها.. إضافة إلى عمليات الفلترة عليهابناء على عدة خيارات متاحة "
})
 .filter('highlight', function ($sce) {
        return function (text, searchSrting) {
            if(searchSrting){
                searchSrting = searchSrting.split(/\s+/);
                if(typeof text !== "undefined")
                    for (var i = 0; i < searchSrting.length; i++) {
                        text = text.replace(new RegExp('(' + searchSrting[i] + ')', 'gi'),
                            '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')
                    }
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
            }
        }
    })
```

```css
.highlighted{
  background-color : yellow
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="main">
  <label>search</label>
  <input ng-model="searchString"/>
  <div ng-if="!searchString">{{content}}</div>
  <div ng-if="searchString" ng-bind-html="content | highlight:searchString"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this seems like an issue with applying regex to Unicode, which is something that is a bit specialized; very few people working with angular will know about regexes and Arabic script.  you may want to try adding a few other tags to your question.

Comment: Done :) , thank you for this suggestion @Claies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a couple of [zero-width-joiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) before and at the end of your highlight spans to make the characters join up properly:

```
text = text.replace(new RegExp('(' + searchSrting[i] + ')', 'gi'),
   '&zwj;<span class="highlighted">$1&zwj;</span>')
```